# Internal server error Django

Tags: django

I just made an update on my Django script and now it just gives me an Internal server error. It runs on a Linux Debian server and sometimes I get an Internal server error and smoetimes I get a TypeError:

Exception Value: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'core'

How to fix this?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Without code or more information, it is not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

to try to find the error, try to run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or try this:

```
python manage.py validate
```

sometimes this work for me to find some error.

Comment: >> python manage.py validate
Unknown command: 'validate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

UPDATE: 'python manage.py check' works.